# null pointer in loop

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to make a program which can dispense change for a given amount. Basically I have a method to see if a given value can be met by the currencies in stock.

This is the loop:

```
    private int check(int v)
    { 
        int in = v;
        for (int i = valueTable.Length; i >= 0; i--)//from biggest coin to smallest
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < supplyTable[i-1]; j++)//for the supply of the particular coin
            {
                if (in >= coinValueTable[i-1] && coinSupplyTable[i+1] > 0)
                    in -= coinValueTable[i-1];
            }
        }
        return rt;
    }
```

When running debug, it appears that the first iteration of the outer loop only establishes the second loop, and does not execute it. The inner loop is only executed on the outer loop's second iteration, essentially meaning that I miss the last value in the valueTable. I've played around a bit with the for loops, but it always seems to miss then ends of the array.

Any ideas as to why the inner loop doesn't run for the first iteration of the outerloop? Thanks in advance.

Comment: coinSupplyTable[i+1] lead to IndexOutOfBoundException when i >= coinValueTable.Length-1

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: PLease don't mark questions "SOLVED". Instead, choose an answer as the "accepted" answer and people will know that you're not looking for more answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set `coinSupplyTable[7] == 0`, so naturally the first iteration, which takes the last element, has condition `j < 0`, which is immediately false and thus the loop does not run.
Nothing wrong there; no stock means no inner loop.

Also, your `if` condition inside the inner loop is not correct. You access `coinSupplyTable[i+1]`, which will lead to an Index out of Range exception.

Finally, are you sure you need the inner loop? It seems to me that you only need the outer loop to iterate over each coin type, and then check the supply.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. I honestly could not see that gap. 

Can you suggest a rough guideline for nested loops? I'm still fairly new to c# and would appreciate anything you could throw at me.

Comment: @M2065: It's hard to give a guideline for loops, as these mostly arise from a need. But I guess a guideline is always start with the least amount of loops. Start with none, if you then find yourself having to access a list, array, collection or anything like that then you add a loop to iterate over it. Then, I guess, guideline number two: start over again as if the outer loop wasn't there, and only if you find that you need to iterate over a different collection, or over the same collection but independently (like comparing each item to every other item), do you add another loop.

Comment: For the rest, it comes with experience, but as a rule of the thumb you need only 1 loop for 1D collections, 2 for 2D collections. 2 loops for comparison operations, but often the inner loop can be tweaked to not having to loop over all indices. Don't worry about knowing everything, just start by understanding 1 loop. If you run into further problems, ask a new question here :)